# Method receiving class references that share the same inherited class

Tags: generics, kotlin, junit

Let's say I have this code in a JUnit test in Kotlin:

```
sealed class InvalidField(val value: String): Exception()
data class InvalidName(val name: String): InvalidField(name)
data class InvalidEmail(val email: String): InvalidField(email)
data class InvalidPassword(val password: String): InvalidField(password)

data class TestCase(exceptionType: WHAT_IS_HERE)

fun `test cases of all exceptions`() = setOf(
   // create instances of TestCases with each exception. how?
)

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("test cases of all exceptions")
fun `test invalid name`(testCase: TestCase) {
   // how can I access the testCase.exceptionType from here?
}
```

The constraint of `WHAT_IS_HERE` should be that **`exceptionType` class references should inherit from `InvalidField`**.
I know that generics are probably the answer. But how? Note that I want to pass class references within `TestCase`'s rather than their instances.

How could I solve this?

Comment: For the second question, you want [reified inline funs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

Comment: For the first question, you want an [upper-bounding formal (generic) parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are a few corrections, as this code doesn't compile. `sealed` class cannot be `data class`, it simply doesn't make sense.
Also, you don't have to nest your data classes inside `sealed` class, it's just a styling preference.
Also, data classes need at least one member, and you didn't specify any. So, let's say that's your resulting code:

```
sealed class InvalidField(val value: String): Exception()
data class InvalidName(val name: String): InvalidField(name)
data class InvalidEmail(val email: String): InvalidField(email)
data class InvalidPassword(val password: String): InvalidField(password)
```

Now let's say your `TestCase` only needs to accept children of `InvalidField`:

```
data class TestCase<out T : InvalidField>(val exceptionType: T)
```

Then your test will look like this:

```
class MyTest {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("cases")
    fun `test invalid name`(testCase: TestCase<InvalidField>) {
        // Any TestCase has exceptionType
        println(testCase.exceptionType)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun cases() = setOf<TestCase<InvalidField>>(
            TestCase(InvalidName("abc"))
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alexey. Thanks for the corrections. Sorry for the errors, but I had the question in my mind and the code was not easily accessible. I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Also, considering the just added `@ParameterizedTest`, what would be the proper declaration of argument `testCase: TestCase<???>`?

Comment: Seems like you don't need factory method after all. I've updated my answer, so now you can also see how those classes can be instantiated and used